# Spirit Qi semantic actions and parameters for functions unrelated to the parser

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-qi

How would I declare a semantic action that calls a free function that doesn't use the attribute the rule/parser returned?

Like, let's say we have a parser that returns a string, but I want to call an unrelated function like Beep, which takes two integer values for frequency and duration and does not care for strings?

Is it actually possible to call it directly, or do I always have to write a proxy function which consumes the string and calls, in this case, Beep in it's body?

Edit:
My apologies.
I should have mentioned that I used boost::phoenix::bind at first with the syntax Hartmut suggested, which gave me this error:

```
could not deduce template argument for 'RT (__cdecl *)(T0,T1)' from 'BOOL (__stdcall *)(DWORD,DWORD)'
```

Is it the calling convention that messes things up here?

Edit2:
Seems that's the problem, Hartmuts code compiles with a plain function that takes the same amount and types of arguments as Beep.

```
example:
bool foo(DWORD a, DWORD b)
{
}

px::bind(&foo,123,456); //compiles
px::bind(&Beep,123,456); // doesn't compile and generates the error message above.
```

A google search revealed to me that (most) WINAPI functions use the __stdcall convention, which is not the default convention, __cdecl, which C/C++ functions with the compiler option /Gd use, like in this case: foo

So the answers given so far were all correct, the phoenix solution just didn't work out of the box for me.
(Which motivated me to post this question in the first place. I'm sorry for it's undignified and confusing nature, maybe this clears it all up now.)

The only thing unclear to me now is...how I would make phoenix get along with __stdcall, but that should probably be a separate question.

Comment: I don't understand--what is the difference between the Beep function you mentioned originally and the new "plain function that takes the same arguments as Beep"?

Comment: Well, I'm still a beginner, so my answer will most likely be non technical or even incorrect, but since "bool foo(DWORD, DWORD)" complies and Beep doesn't, makes it seem to me that foo might get compiled with a different calling convention, but as I said, I'm a rookie, so this might as well be magic to me. One just works, the other doesn't, and all I did was exchange functions pointed to, leaving the rest of the syntax as suggested.

Comment: Oh I see, the calling convention is the problem!  That's documented here: http://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/bind/bind.html#stdcall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As John said you could use `boost::bind`. You have to be very careful not to mix and match placeholder variables from different libraries, though. When using `boost::bind` you need to use its placeholder variables, i.e. `::_1` (yes, boost::bind's placeholders are in global namespace - yuck).

The best solution (and the safest in terms of compatibility) is to utilize `boost::phoenix::bind`. This is compatible with `boost::bind` and anything you can do there is possible with `phoenix::bind` as well (and more). Moreover, Spirit 'understands' Phoenix constructs and exposes all of it's internals using special placeholder variables which are implemented using Phoenix themselves.

In your case the code would look like:

```
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;
some_parser[phx::bind(&Beep, 123, 456)];
```

which will call `Beep(123, 456)` whenever `some_parser` matches.

Comment: That was my very first attempt, since I'm in the process of getting more toe to toe with parsers that actually do some processing instead of just filling structs with an external post process step, my apologies for leaving that bit out.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you can use [Boost Bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/bind/bind.html).  Instead of writing a wrapper function and giving its address to Qi, you could do this:

```
boost::bind( Beep, 123, 456 );
```

This will build a binding which discards its own arguments and calls `Beep(123, 456)`.  If you wanted to pass its argument along as well (not that you do here, just to illustrate something common), you can do this:

```
boost::bind( Beep, 123, 456, _1 );
```

Then it will call `Beep(123, 456, the_string)`